# Summation of electromagnetic waves gives a Poynting vector with $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields not perpendicular to each other

Tags: electromagnetism

I am interested in getting the overall intensity (which is defined as $I\equiv \,\langle S \rangle$) with 2 or more beams of coherent and monochromatic plane waves at the same frequency. I understand that the Poynting vector is not linear so I will have to construct the new $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields separately and then construct the summed Poynting vector. But this method has an issue: Once I add $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields independently, the summed $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields are no longer perpendicular to each other, and thus the overall intensity is reduced due to the $\sin\theta $ carried in the cross product. Is this look correct? Should the new beam be an ordinary EM wave as well (if not then how to sum fields correctly)? Please help!

Comment: this may help if you print it out https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/8/8.02t/www/materials/ExamPrep/finalexam/ps11_sol_v04.pdf

Comment: Thx~this do provide a lot hints :)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If the beams are linearly polarized and have a phase shift of $\pi$ then they interfere destructively, so this makes perfect sense :)

---

Proof like I promised in the comment:
Assume two plane waves with $\vec{E_1}\perp \vec{B_1} $ and $\vec{E_2}\perp \vec{B_2} $.

Lets look at the dot product of the sums:

$$(\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2})\cdot (\vec{B_1}+\vec{B_2})=\vec{E_1}\cdot \vec{B_1} + \vec{E_1}\cdot \vec{B_2} + \vec{E_2}\cdot \vec{B_1} + \vec{E_2}\cdot \vec{B_2}$$
But the first and last terms are $0$ because the fields are perpendicular.
We remain with
$$\vec{E_1}\cdot \vec{B_2} + \vec{E_2} \cdot \vec{B_1}=E_1 B_2 \cos \theta_{E_1 B_2} + E_2B_1\cos \theta_{E_2 B_1} $$
Now, because $E=cB$ you can see that $E_1 B_2 = E_2 B_1 $. If you draw to your self the vectors you can prove quite easily that the angles add up to $180^\circ$ meaning they have the same cosines just with a different sign, so the whole product is $0$ and the sum of each field are perpendicular!

QED

Comment: If one beam is polarized in y direction and the other 30 degrees to y direction, then what will be the intensity? Unfortunately I don't know if they even interfere or not...

Comment: Then there won't be perfect constructive interference, but the fields will interfere to make a new wave with strong y component and a weak x component so the light will be polarized with an angle $\theta < 30^\circ $. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because when we construct the new Poynting vector, this new light beam won't have E and B field perpendicular to each other, which may mean either the newly constructed thing is not a light beam, or we are doing something wrong. Any idea on explaining the intensity calculation with those 2 waves?

Comment: Why do you think they won't be perpendicular? I'll add another answer with proof they are (because it's easier to type math in an answer than a comment)

Comment: Try the E field in 1st quadrant and B field in the 2nd, and for the other beam try the E field in the 4th and B field in the 3rd. The combined E and B fields are not perpendicular.

Comment: Yeah but they don't travel to the same direction... then you don't have a traveling wave

Comment: Interference works on standing waves as well. Once waves are formed, direction shouldn't matter.

Comment: But why are you assuming that for a standing wave $E=cB , E\perp B$? That comes from Maxwell's equation and assuming a plane wave

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this answer although it does not directly address the problem to clear up a few things:

Light beams are composed out of [innumerable photons in confluence,](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) and both, photons and emergent beams obey their respective Maxwell equations,  ([quantized](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002/files/0604169.pdf) and [classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) respectively).

When paradoxes appear analyzing data classically it means that the quantum mechanical formulation is necessary to understand what is happening.

> I am interested in getting the overall intensity (which is defined as$I\equiv \,<S>$ ) with 2 or more beams of coherent and monochromatic plane waves at the same frequency.

This experiment has been carried out  [with lasers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU)  the split beam interfering  at the screen.

So you can see in the video that the actual power falling on the screen can be from zero, to two blobs on each other, to interference patterns. So there is no conservation of energy at the screen. What is happening with conservation of energy? [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg) by the same professor demonstrates the quantum mechanical nature of light, where one has to count everything the source included in the quantum mechanical solution, which picks up the slack of energy conservation.

So the superposition of the two classical beams needs the knowledge of the quantum mechanical sources  to really follow the energy pattern ( the Poynting vector is an energy measure). The lazing phenomenon is par excellence a quantum mechanical phenomenon.

Now about adding E and B fields you are ignoring that the sinusoidal form that allows additions happens in the plane wave solution. Adding stuff no longer are a single plane wave. Either the plane waves cross at some plane, when you see the effect in the video above, or they have an angle and each goes through unaffected, unless a screen or measurement is done at the  crossover point. If they are completely superposed, they are the same beam, or if added by a beam splitter  back to the exact same direction the phase will give effects as in the video the interference patterns will subtract from the energy, so the phase between the two beams has to be back to 0.

I also want to emphasize that superposition is not interaction. Quantum mechanically it is the wave functions that are superposed and will show interference patterns; the interaction is what happens at the lazing source.

Comment: Is it acceptable to say that from a two source interference arrangement producing $\cos^2$ fringes the average power is equal to the sum of the individual powers produced by the sources? In effect the result of interference is the channelling of light along certain directions.

Comment: @Farcher for two independent sources , two lasers lets say, I would say yes. here: http://scienceblogs.com/principles/2010/11/15/how-do-you-see-interference-be/ it suggests that it is the analogue of one source two slits.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know any sources explaining interference between waves/photons polarized in different angles?  (and if possible may come from different directions and intersect at one point?) Thanks a lot!

Comment: not off hand. I suggest to google " interference between waves/photons polarized in different angles?". Usually something useful pops up

Comment: Quick question: Is the construction of Poynting vector with 2 or more beams/photons valid inside 1 wavelength? Is quantum mechanics has to be applied? Thanks!